# Implementing Page with Filtering

Tags: java, spring, jpa, service, pageable

i have this repository, service and controller, and i have no ideea how to solve the error that i m getting in service, any suggestions please? **`(Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<UtenteDto> to Page<UtenteDto>)`**

```
String FILTER_UTENTE_NOME_AND_COGNOME_QUERY = "select b from Utente b where UPPER(b.nome) like CONCAT('%',UPPER(?1),'%') and UPPER(b.cognome) like CONCAT('%',UPPER(?2),'%')";
@Query(FILTER_UTENTE_NOME_AND_COGNOME_QUERY)
List<Utente> findByFirstNameLikeAndLastNameLike(String nomeFilter, String cognomeFilter,Pageable pageable);
```

```
public Page<UtenteDto> findByFirstNameLikeAndLastNameLike(String nomeFilter, String cognomeFilter, int page, int size){
  Pageable pageable= PageRequest.of(page, size);
  return utenteRepository.findByFirstNameLikeAndLastNameLike(nomeFilter,cognomeFilter,pageable)
          .stream()
          .map(e->mapper.map(e,UtenteDto.class))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/utenti")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public Page<UtenteDto> getAllFilteredByNomeAndCognome(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String nomeFilter,
                                                      @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String cognomeFilter,
                                                      @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                                      @RequestParam(defaultValue = "30") int size){
  AccessTokenAccountRepository repository;
  return utenteService.findByFirstNameLikeAndLastNameLike(nomeFilter,cognomeFilter,page,size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is declared to return `Page`, but you are actually returning `List`.

Work with a page instead, best would be to change repository method to return `Page` and then use [map()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to change entities to dtos.

```
Page<Utente> page = get from repo;
Page<UtenteDto> dtoPage = page.map(e -> mapper.map(e,UtenteDto.class));
```